# C expression must have integral or enum type?

Tags: c, struct

So I've got this.

```
#define MAX_MENU_OPTIONS 1

typedef struct _NEW_MENU_OPTION
{
    char* name;
    int type;
    char* opt1;
    int value1;
    int cycleid;
    int cycle_max;
    int cycle_min;
    int onenter;
} NEW_MENU_OPTION;

NEW_MENU_OPTION menu_options[MAX_MENU_OPTIONS];
```

Then later in the code I have.

```
switch(menu_options[menu_location].onenter)
{
case 0:
    break;
}
```

But I've got a red error thing on menu_options saying "Error: expression must have integral or enum type".  I'm really confused and I can't see what's wrong, what is wrong?

Comment: what is menu_location? It's not declared anywhere in the code shown here...

Comment: maybe a missing semi-colon some line(s) before? Your code looks correct...

Comment: It's an int, sorry, forgot to paste it.  Also the previous line is fine.

Comment: Hmm this seems to compile fine with C99 with the Apple LLVM compiler.

Comment: Are you working in Visual Studio? Is this an IntelliSense error? You might try rebuilding the project and see if you get an actual compiler error. The IntelliSense engine sometimes gets confused and reports erroneous "errors". Otherwise, this code [looks fine to me](http://codepad.org/BQzMSjSR).

Comment: Glad that fixed it; I've graduated my comment to an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you've posted looks fine to me, and CodePad compiles it just fine in a [quick little test](http://codepad.org/BQzMSjSR).

So although the question doesn't mention it, I'm going to guess that you're working in Visual Studio.

In that case, it's very likely that the error you're seeing is an *IntelliSense* error, rather than an actual compiler error. Sometimes the IntelliSense engine (implemented using a different compiler) gets confused and reports errors that you've already fixed in the code. I notice this problem often when refactoring existing code.

The fix is to build/compile your project and verify that the error goes away. You should see a clean "Error List" window after a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, expressions don't have to be integral. An expression can evaluate to a pointer.

In some contexts, however, C requires an integral value.
In this example, there are two such cases:
1. The value you give switch() - seems OK here, because onenter is int.
2. The array index - you didn't show its type, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this code!

But you need to ensure that `menu_location` and `menu_options[menu_location].onenter` are initialized/assigned valid integer values something like the below.

```
    int menu_location = 0;
    menu_options[menu_location].onenter = 0;
```

I compiled it with `gcc` with `-Wall` option and found it fine!